# NUnit Playwright - Multiple inheritance BaseTests and PageTest

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nunit, playwright-dotnet

How to achieve the equivalent of multiple inheriting from a custom `BaseTests` class and Playwright's `PageTest` class?

### Problem

I have 2 types of tests in my application: Non-playwright and Playwright-ones.

Both types share common `SetUp` code found in `BaseTests` and should inherit from `BaseTests`.

However, Playwright tests should also inherit from Playwright's `PageTest`.

I've tried making Playwright tests inherit from both `BaseTests` and `PageTest`, but multiple inheritance is not possible in C# AFAIK.

### Solutions tried

(1) To make `BaseTests` an interface instead of a class. However, I found that NUnit doesn't call `BaseTests`'s `SetUp` in that case.

(2) To add an `abstract class BasePageTests : PageTest` and duplicate the code of `BaseTests` in it. Actually, I do already have a `BasePageTests` since there's more `SetUp` code specific to Playwright only. But I'd rather make it `BasePageTests: BaseTests, PageTest` not duplicate the code of `BaseTests`'s `SetUp` in `BasePageTests`.

### Code

```cs
abstract class BaseTests {
  protected virtual CustomWebApplicationFactoryOptions? ConfigureCustomWebApplicationFactoryOptions() => null;

  [SetUp]
  public void BaseTestsSetUp() {
    // Lots of set-up code. E.g., cleaning up the database.
  }
}

class SampleNonPlaywrightTest : BaseTests {
  // ...
}

// `BasePageTests` needs `BaseTests`'s SetUp, but also has its own SetUp code.
// Needs to inherit from Playwright's `PageTest` (or make its children inherit from `PageTest`), but multiple inheritance is not possible!
abstract class BasePageTests : BaseTests, PageTest {
    protected override CustomWebApplicationFactoryOptions? ConfigureCustomWebApplicationFactoryOptions() =>
        new() { StartRealServer = true, BypassAuth = true };

  [SetUp]
  public void BasePageTestsSetUp() {
    // More set-up relevant only to page tests. E.g., calling `_application.CreateClient()` to actually start the server
  }
}

class SamplePlaywrightTest : BasePageTests {
  // ...
}
```

So, in summary: What is the idiomatic way to achieve the above without code duplication?

Comment: What's ```PageTest```? C# can't inherit two class I think you know that and you can try to extract the code in the ```Setup``` to a new class so you don't need to write them two times but still need to ```invoke``` them in two ```setup```

Comment: `PageTest` is a class in Playwright that all test classes must inherit from (AFAIK). Yes, I can do that. One possible complication, though: In `BaseTests` I also have some members variables that I initialize in `SetUp`. E.g., a `DbContext`, an `IMapper`, a Scope, .. etc. Defining them in each test class is a bit duplicate-y. Perhaps if I have the method you talk about and its interface is `X(out DBContext, out IMapper, .. etc.)`, that'd make it easier to propagate any new members to all test classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make BaseTest inherit PageTest, so that way your playwright test can use use is which inheirts from BaseTest which would inherit from PageTest

**Child Class --> BaseTest --> PageTest**

Also in case you are using **PageObjects** then your Page Objects can directly inherit from PageTest without the need of base class

and your TestClasses can go via **BaseTest --> PageTest**